# Win10 update messed my dual boot. Help please

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-10

My first post, asking for help...

I had (have) a dual boot with Ubuntu and Win10. An upgrade on win10 appeared, it said it was going to restart several times and after the first (or second, not sure) restart, I got the message: "error: no such partition. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>". Right after restarting, can't boot to any OS.

After reading a bit around here, I tried with ls, I can see my two hdd and several partitions, but every time I try /ls (hd#,msdos#), I get the message "filesystem is unknown".

I am able to boot a linux from my usb key. Tried with testdisk, I see my partitions but I don´t know what to do next. 
I also tried with boot-repair, the automatic repair did not work. I got this url:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rVpDmnBW3s/

Can somebody give me some help? Any hint will be appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Comment: Widnows updates in BIOS mode do not rewrite Linux logical partitions back into partition table. You can restore: http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/944371/grub-and-ubuntu-disappeared-after-windows-update Parted rescue seems easier than testdisk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/665445/upgraded-to-windows-10-on-dual-boot-and-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-partition

Comment: I tried parted and testdisk (actually I followed your old posts). I can see 5 partitions on testdisk, and I was able to navigate through my files on both linux and windows from the linux live cd, so nothing is really broken. But when I try parted rescue, nothing happens. In testdisk I do not know how to define the partition table so it boots. Thanks for answering

Comment: I never have restored a partition. But suggested both from other questions & posts. With parted rescue you have to use sectors for start & end. In your case the start  of extended or 403,462,142 and start of swap or 471,824,384. There are one or two sectors between partitions, so those are approximate. With testdisk it sees all your old versions of partitions. You have to select combination that does not overlap but includes missing partition. Did you back up partition table, so if change not correct you can get back to start. And if in Testdisk you see your data, back that up.

Answer (score 0):

From your boot-repair output, I don't even see your Ubuntu install anywhere. However, you should be able to at least boot Windows from the "grub rescue>" prompt.

Try firing these three commands from grub rescue>

```
set root=(hd1,msdos2)
chainloader +1
boot
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried, chainloader and boot are "unknown" for my grub rescue.